# Auto lock if Smart Stay can't see my eyes open

Tags: samsung, security, lock-screens

Sometimes, while in bed, I will watch a movie or YouTube on my Samsung Galaxy S20 ultra. Sometimes I fall asleep and the movie will continue to play as I sleep. I don't want my son wandering in the room and see King Leonidas stab well... everyone.

Is there a way I can have my device turn off my screen and lock my phone if the front camera sees my eyes close? Smart Stay app doesn't seem to do anything.